# Credentials in URL for Python "Requests" library

Tags: python, credentials, url

Will using the following code result in credentials being passed in the URL?
I know it is a GET method, but how does the python requests library process this?
Does it attach it to the URL or attach it to the headers?Any secure alternatives to using this?

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.get('https://example.com/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: this is a python internals question or a HTTP internals question, not a security question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) does not pass the credentials in the URL but in an `Authentication` header field. The credentials are only base64 encoded and not encrypted, so it should only be used over HTTPS - which you do here.